# Android Trouble saving text from Edit Text View to database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my application, I am allowing user to send a `alert message` to some numbers. User can write any text of his own choice in the `EditText` or he can select a text from the pre-defined text from the `spinner`. Earlier I was saving the text to the `SharedPreferences` but now I want it to be in `SQLite`.I am able to save the contact numbers to the database for which user wants to send the message but I am having trouble in saving the message to database. I want that when user entered his own text or selected any text from the `spinner` after that he press save button and the text is saved to database.Please Help.
P.S _ I think am having trouble in calling method from database to button onclick.
Please have a look on my code and suggest me what to do.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    String separator = "; ";
    private Button btn_cntct;
    private EditText message;
    LinearLayout linearLayoutSec;
    private Button GPSState;
    Button b_alert;
    Button b_save_message;
    public int REQUESTCODE = 1;
    int temp;
    ScrollView ScrView;
    Context c = MainActivity.this;
    Button AlertMessages;
    private static ArrayList<ContactItems> selectedContactList = new ArrayList<ContactItems>();
    static CustomAdapter adapter;
    public static String[] myvalue = new String[1];
    Spinner spinner;
    static String[] alert = { " ", "I am in danger", "Help Me", "Watch Out",
            "Look For Me", "Cover ME" };
    MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    String savedMessage;
    Button save;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
    // message.setFocusable(false);
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    String dis = dbHelper.getMsg();
    if (dis != null) {
        message.setText(dis);
    }

    bsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_save);
    bsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str = message.getText().toString();
            dbHelper.updateMsg(str);

        }
    });




    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spin_alert_message);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            alert);
    spinner.setAdapter(adp);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {

            String selectedItem = alert[position];
            message.setText(selectedItem);

            // loads the text that has been stored to SP and set it to
            // EditText
            //message.setText(pref.getString("AutoSave", ""));
            // to bring cursor to front
            message.setSelection(message.getText().length());



        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

    /************************** saving custom message *****************************/

    // for saving text that user can change as per need

    ListView contactlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListitems);
    Resources res = getResources();
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, selectedContactList, res,MainActivity.this);
    contactlist.setAdapter(adapter);

        /********************************* GPS *******************************/

        // checking if GPS is already on or not.
        // If not then displaying the alert dialog
        // requesting user to On GPS.
        GPSState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGPSstate);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false; //
        // Declaring a Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled) {
            // no GPS provider is enabled
            // displaying GPS status on the button and and opening GPS settings

            GPSState.setText("GPS is off.turn it on");
            GPSState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivityForResult(
                            new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                            REQUESTCODE);

                }
            });
            // setting up the dialog box for GPS Settings

            // creating alertdialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

            builder.setTitle("Settings");
            builder.setMessage("Enable GPS for the Application");

            builder.setPositiveButton("GPS Setting",

            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle("How to use Application")
                                    .setMessage(
                                            "You must enable the GPS in order to use this application. Press Activate and then press Power Button twice in order to send the alert message to the selected contacts")
                                    .setNeutralButton(
                                            "OK",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                                    // do something // for //
                                                    // returning back to // //
                                                    // application
                                                    dialog.cancel();

                                                }
                                            }).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

            builder.show();

        } else {
            GPSState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivityForResult(
                            new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                            REQUESTCODE);
                }
            });
        }

        // defining button elements for picking contacts from phone-book
        btn_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpickperson);
        btn_cntct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (selectedContactList.size() < 4) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // using Intent for fetching contacts from phone-book
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
                } else {
                    // print toast for not allowing user to add more contacts
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You Can Only Add 4 Contacts ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // calling onActivityResult when contacts has been selected from the
    // phone-book, giving back the REQUESTCODE i started it with, the RC it
    // returned with
    // any additional data from it.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
        GPSState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGPSstate);
        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled)
            GPSState.setText("GPS is off.Turn it on");
        else
            GPSState.setText("GPS is on");

        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.i("data", uri.toString());
            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver()
                            .query(uri,
                                    new String[] {
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                    null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        final ContactItems item = new ContactItems(
                                c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getInt(2));
                        item.setName(c.getString(0));
                        item.setNumber(c.getString(1));
                        item.setType(c.getInt(2));
                        selectedContactList.add(item);

                        Set<ContactItems> s = new TreeSet<ContactItems>(
                                new Comparator<ContactItems>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public int compare(ContactItems o1,
                                            ContactItems o2) {
                                        // for preventing duplicacy of contacts
                                        // and calling toast
                                        if (o1.number.equals(o2.number)) {

                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Selected Number Already Exists",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {


                                        }
                                        return o1.getNumber().compareTo(
                                                o2.getNumber());

                                    }
                                });

                        s.addAll(selectedContactList);
                        selectedContactList.clear();
                        selectedContactList.addAll(s);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // save the task list to preference

                        dbHelper.insertContact(item);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*
     * @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     * super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // You put the content of your list,
     * which is this.mCachedData, in the // state
     * outState.putParcelableArrayList("ABC", selectedContactList); }
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
        GPSState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGPSstate);
        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled)
            GPSState.setText("GPS is off.Turn it on");
        else
            GPSState.setText("GPS is on");
    }

}// final parentheses
```

MySQLiteHelper.java

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

      public static final String TABLE_NAME = "userdetails";
      public static final String TABLE_NAME_MSG = "usermessage";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "NUMBER";
      public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
      public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID_MSG = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_MSG = "message";
      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userInformation.db";

      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
      private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

      // Database creation sql statement
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS = "create table "
          + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
          + " text not null,"+COLUMN_NUMBER+"  text not null,"+COLUMN_TYPE+" text not null);";
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_MSG = "create table "
              + TABLE_NAME_MSG + "(" + COLUMN_ID_MSG
              + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_MSG    + " text not null);";
      private static final String DATABASE_INSERT_MSG = "insert into  "
              + TABLE_NAME_MSG + "(" + COLUMN_MSG+") VALUES('enter your message');";


      public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_MSG);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_INSERT_MSG);

      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
      }

      public long insertContact(ContactItems contItem) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_NAME, contItem.getName());
            values.put(COLUMN_NUMBER, contItem.getNumber());
            values.put(COLUMN_TYPE, contItem.getType());

            // insert row
            long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

            // assigning tags to todo
            /*for (long tag_id : tag_ids) {
                createTodoTag(todo_id, tag_id);
            }*/

            return result;
        }


      public ArrayList<ContactItems> getAllContacts() {
          ArrayList<ContactItems> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactItems>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

            Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    ContactItems conItems = new ContactItems();
                    conItems.setName(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME))));
                    conItems.setNumber((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NUMBER))));
                    conItems.setType(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TYPE))));

                    // adding to todo list
                    contactList.add(conItems);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

            return contactList;
        }

    public void updateMsg(String msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // String selectQuery = "update  " + TABLE_NAME_MSG+" set "+COLUMN_MSG+" = '"+msg+"' where "+COLUMN_ID_MSG+" = 1";
          ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_MSG, msg);
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         db.update(TABLE_NAME_MSG, values, null, null);

    }
    public String getMsg() {
        String message ="";
          String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_MSG;

          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MSG));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e(LOG, "message = "+message);
        return message;

    }

    public int removeData(String number) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
           //db.drawQuery(deleteQuery, null);
          return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NUMBER + "='" + number+"'", null) ;

    }

    }
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<ContactItems> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public Resources res;

    MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    // ListModel tempValues=null;
    int i = 0;
    String selectedNum = " ";
    Context contxt;

    /************* CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<ContactItems> d,
            Resources resLocal,Context context) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        res = resLocal;
        contxt= context;
        dbHelper= new MySQLiteHelper(contxt);

        /*********** Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
    public int getCount() {

        if (data.size() <= 0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView text;
        public TextView textNumber;

        public ImageView image;

    }

    /****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int pos = position;
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        // check if converView is null, if it is null it probably means
        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlistitem, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/
            // if it is not null, just reuse it from the recycler
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
            holder.textNumber = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contactnumber);
            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.deleteimage);

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        if (data.size() <= 0) {

            holder.text.setText("Add");
            holder.textNumber.setText(" ");
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/

            /************ Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

            holder.text.setText("" + data.get(position).getName());

            holder.textNumber.setText("" + data.get(position).getNumber());
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.image.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("delete_button",
                    null, null));

            holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            activity);
                    build.setTitle("Delete");
                    build.setMessage("Are You Sure");
                    build.setPositiveButton("Delete",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    dbHelper.removeData(data.get(pos).getNumber());
                                    data.remove(pos);
                                    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                    /*
                     * data.remove(pos);
                     * MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     */
                    build.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    build.show();
                }

            });
            /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row *******/

        }
        // return the view for a single item in the listview
        return vi;
    }

}
```

ContactItems.java

```
public class ContactItems implements Parcelable {
    String name = "";
    String number = "";
    int type = 0;

    public ContactItems(String name, String number, int type) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ContactItems(Parcel source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.name = source.readString();
        this.number = source.readString();
        this.type = source.readInt();
    }
    public ContactItems() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContactItems> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ContactItems>() {

        @Override
        public ContactItems createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ContactItems(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ContactItems[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ContactItems[size];
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(number);
        dest.writeInt(type);

    }
```

Comment: Where your facing the problem ? any errors ?

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy i don't know what to do on onclick of save button in MainActivity.java.

Comment: get all the values which are you want to store send those values to Sqlite to store

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy i have no idea . I am a beginner. Can you please elaborate sir

Comment: Where you are getting the text of your spinner as well as your edittext ? You have not written any code in your save button click to save the message into database!!! What are you implementing can you please tell me? Do you get proper message from your `EditText` or `Spinner` ?

Comment: @GrIsHu I don't know what to write in save button click to save the message to database. I am even confused on how to get the text of spinner and of edit text . Please help

Comment: You will have to manage for both the `Spinner` as well as `EditText`. Because at time i think you are allowing user to add/select the text for both `EditText` and `Spinner`.

Comment: @GrIsHu yes yes . I am allowing user to either display his own text or select any text from the spinner that will get display to edit text

Comment: How you are managing to get the text either from `EditText` or from `Spinner` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47913/discussion-between-bhanu-kaushik-and-grishu)

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the method for inserting or updating the message into database in your button's click and before calling that method just get the value of `EditText` into some variable and pass that variable as parameter for inserting into database.

Try out as below:

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String str = message.getText().toString(); 
             dbHelper.updateMsg(str);
        }
    });
```

**EDITED:**

```
public boolean updateMsg(String msg) {

          ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_MSG, msg);
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       return  db.update(TABLE_NAME_MSG, values, COLUMN_ID_MSG +"=1"+, null)>0;

    }
```

Comment: i followed your code and i typed something in edit text and press save button and then i checked the database from SQLite browser. the data is getting saved to the data. The only thing is once I restart the emulator, the data is not getting displayed on the edit text

Comment: What do you mean by not getting displayed on `EditText` ? Which data you want to show in EditText ?

Comment: suppose i typed "Bhanu Kaushik" on edit text and pressed save button. and then I restarted the emulator I want that Bhanu Kaushik to remain on the edit text view

Comment: For that you will have to temporarily store its value into sharedpreference if you want it back. If you have already entered it. OnClick of save button or on any kind of events.

Comment: for displaying data, I called the getMsg() method from my database on onCreate(). but the application is getting crashed. please check the edited post.If I am doing something wrong

Comment: Where you have created and instance of `dbHelper` class? @bhanukaushik Just add the line `dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(this);` before calling `getMsg()` method.

Comment: MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

Comment: @bhanukaushik Just add the line `dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(this);` before calling `getMsg()` method.

Comment: I did what you told me and edited the answer, but its not still displaying the text :(

Comment: What is your crash ? Please post your crash error. And remove unncessary code of `ContactItems.java` and Adapter code which is no needed.

Comment: no, the application is not getting crashed now. Since, i added dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(this);

Comment: Then what is the issue now ?

Comment: I typed "Bhanu Kaushik" pressed save. 
Restarts emulator and no "Bhanu Kaushik" in edit text.
No application crash, No errors.
"Bhanu Kaushik" getting saved to database also . I pulled the database file and checked it

Comment: Its because you are fetching all the records from database. Do you actually get records inserted into database?

Comment: Change your query as to get the message `"String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_MSG +"WHERE COLUMN_ID_MSG=1"+;`

Comment: Sorry change your query as `"String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_MSG +" WHERE "+ COLUMN_ID_MSG +" =1 "+;`

Comment: same ... Syntax error on token "+", ++ expected 
its showing error on the last +;

Comment: `String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_MSG +" WHERE "+ COLUMN_ID_MSG +" =1 ";`

Comment: still not working ... but thank you sir.. for involving your so much time into this ... thanks a lot .. i will like into this, what i can do into it

Comment: Query is correct i don't know why its throwing syntax error. Is your table contains more than one list of records ? If its so than as you are returning data and storing it into simple string its overriding the old string value and may be because of that you are not getting the message.

Comment: don't knw.. is it also a thing that I am running it on emulator. Cause I have read some times results may vary from real device

Comment: Do onething uninstall the old application and install the new one and then try out.